# Declaration of class must be compatible with interface

Tags: php

```
Comparare.php
    <?php
    interface Comparare{
    public function compara(self $a);
    }
    ?>

clasa.php
<?php
class Clasa implements Comparare{
    public $v;
    public function compara(self $a){
        if($this->v < $a->v)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if($this->v==$a->v)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    function __construct($a){
        $this->v=$a;
    }
}
?>
test.php
<?php
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once ($class_name) . ".php";
}
function maxim(Comparare $a,Comparare $b){
    if ($a->compara($b)<0){
        return $b;
    }
    else {
        return $a;
    }
}
$x=new Clasa(7);
$y=new Clasa(8);
$max=maxim($x,$y);
echo "maximul este:" . $max;
?>
```

> Fatal error: Declaration of Clasa::compara() must be compatible with
>   Comparare::compara(Comparare $a) in
>   D:\xammp\htdocs\php\clase\comparare\clasa.php on line 3

I use XAMPP 3.2.2( PHP Version 5.5.33 )

Comment: Your code is kind of confusing with English and Spanish(?) identifiers intermixed like that. Better stick to just English for consistency, because the entire language and standard library are in English.

Comment: My code is in romanian language. This is not a problem.

Comment: You don't think it looks weird when half of the code is in English and half in Romanian?

Comment: I know this. Is just for test because i learn.Doesn't matter name of vars

Comment: Learning good naming is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` type in your interface refers to the interface - in your class it refers to the class. Those are two different types. You need to use the interface type name when defining the method in order for the types to match. When implementing an interface method, the signature, including the types, has to match for the implementation to be picked up.

```
public function compara(Comparare $a) {
```

Comment: Just a note: The op is changing the signature of the method, therefore, not really implementing it...

Comment: Thanks for hint but is not complete. After modify line echo "maximul este:" . $max; in echo "maximul este:" . $max->v; ,it works.

Comment: @LeonardH: It's an answer to your question. I didn't run your code.